# how to calculate for each values of array in python

Tags: python

I am trying to save the .csv file data into an array and then apply my logic.

The image shows the CSV data:

[image]

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

A = []
B = []
X = []

f = open('1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
B.append(row[0])
A.append(row[1])
X.append(row[2])
a = 0
b =1

y = (a+(X-A)*(b-a))/(B-A)

z = array([y])

print (z)
```

while running this code I am getting an error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: Good luck! What's stopping you? Use a loop, use zip, and a few arithmetic operations later, you're done, right?

Comment: as I am new to programming I don't know how to do that ! can you help me out ?

Comment: If you're having trouble finding a place to begin, here's a good link I'd recommend looking into: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Start with one and stick to it.

Comment: You can start with `numpy` array in order to start calculations. I am not sure why you want to divide a list by another list and what you expect output to be.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have create this program my own but I am getting an error in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't simply comment on your question because my reputation isn't high enough, but it seems to me that you have not done any research with regards to this problem because it's simply 2 lines of code. Instead of just telling you the answer I would like to encourage you to research loops in python, but at the risk of losing rep by not actually answering your question in this box there are 2 ways you can accomplish your task:

These methods are based on the assumption that A, B and X in your equation are the indexed values of each of the arrays and that they are all of the same length

method 1 - simple for loop

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  c = (a + (X[i] - A[i]) * (b - a)) / (B[i] - A[i])
```

method 2 - for loop with zipped arrays/lists

```
for i, j, k in zip(A, B, X):
  c = (a + (k - i) * (b - a)) / (j - i)
```